# Magento - Customizing a page?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I just started using Magento, and to me, it seems like a big mess in there...

I'm looking to edit my home page that I got from a template.  It looks great but I took out a bunch of useless static blocks inside of it and now I have wholes everywhere.  Check the link:
http://goo.gl/v5uTx

What I don't seem to find is where is my actual page structure?  I went into the admin and just found this for my home page:

```
    <p>
{{widget type="flexiblewidget/list" column_count="3" limit_count="9"  
if="em_feature_product=1" header="Favorite products" order_by="name asc" 
template="flexiblewidget/featured.phtml"}}
</p>
```

Which is basically a tiny part of the page.

So the question is, **where can I find the rest of my page content and structure** (ie the slideshow, the top offers, ...) so that I can try to re-organise it to look like a website and not cheese?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is different than most other CMS solutions. You may be used to seeing the raw HTML in the CMS page, or at least a good portion of it. However, Magento uses PHP to render blocks onto the page. It gets it's instructions from XML documents inside of your theme. If this is your first time working with Magento, it may be good to check out [this post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento) before you get too frustrated. It will walk you through some basics.

Most likely, the HTML for your slider and top offers are in files inside of your theme directory. Your theme directory will be at app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/ - your php and html will be in the template folder, and the XML instructions will be in the layout folder. The home page, like many other pages on your site are using a main template to load site-wide HTML and CSS. There are 4 of these main templates by default: 1 column, 2 columns with left sidebar, 2 columns with right sidebar, and 3 columns. These main templates can be found in the templates folder under the "page" directory. If you open one of these templates, you will find a line that looks like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

This line is asking the XML instructions for anything under the block named "content". That is most likely where the slider is being assigned. You will have to find the XML file this is being defined in. You may want to familiarize yourself with the layout folder and Magento's fallback hierarchy. Check out [this post](http://www.groovecommerce.com/ecommerce-blog/magento/make-your-magento-installation-upgrade-friendly/).

Hopefully this will help you out with the issues you're having with your page!